# Sending files from bot to user in 1:1 Conversation.

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

Trying to send from bot to user in Microsoft Teams file with format .docx, but this file is not send in conversation. What's the problem it can be?

Tried to send pictures .png and it worked. Sent pictures as attachment and as a picture in HeroCard - it worked...

Answer (score 5):

This feature is currently in Developer Preview. More information here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bots-files

Comment: Can you advice me some workarounds for solving this problem?

Comment: Workaround: host the file somewhere and share only the link?

Comment: I host the file on SharePoint. But what workaround about hosting files on Storage?